# Are there any recommendation to install Content Delivery (8/8.5) on Windows or Linux?

Tags: content-delivery, web8.5, infrastructure

Can someone please help me to understand if I can get an added benefit to setup Content Delivery on Linux instead of Windows.

If I am not wrong, Content Manager can only be set up on Windows as running on IIS web server.

However, our Content Delivery will be hosted on Tomcat servers & we are planning to set up on Linux.

Are there any recommendation from SDL or can someone highlight any pros & cons in this approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Yes, the CM can only run on Windows as it is a .NET based application. Content Delivery, however, is separate and you can deploy to whatever your enterprise standards or needs are.

The answer to the Content Delivery platform question is very custom to each client and their circumstances. It would be unwise to recommend such a major enterprise IT decision on an open forum like this. You have to consider required performance, internal enterprise standards, SLAs, data privacy compliance, security and many more variables.

The approach would be to have a specialist perform an analysis on the situation and present the finding and recommendations as part of an engagement.

Comment: +1 Nick. SDL "support both platforms" and this should be expected to mean the same thing (e.g. CD shouldn't run slowly on one and efficiently in the other - all other things being equal). Whether the *Enterprise* prefer one over the other is more important - the fact SDL support both is just an added benefit of an Enterprise tool.